# Change ASP.NET Core Identity connection string during service registration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to test an ASP.NET Core application using [Alba](https://jasperfx.github.io/alba/guide/gettingstarted.html#snippet-sample_bootstrapping_with_web_application_factory).

The application is using ASP.NET Core Identity (7.0).

Alba allows you to hook into the service registration of your `Program.cs` in the test setup.

So the flow is

- Service registration in `Program.cs`
- Service registration in test setup
- Application/host is build.

In `Program.cs` I'm configuring ASP.NET Core Identity like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(
  options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString)
);

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(
  options => 
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
  )
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();
```

In my test I want to change the connection string for `IdentityDbContext`.

Is this possible?

Replacing the existing `IdentityDbContext` with a different connection string doesn't seem to work (ASP.NET Identity tries to access the context registered in `Program.cs`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying different connection string in the application test project.

In your test class constructor try this

```
private YourDatabaseContext _DatabaseContext;
   
public YourDatabaseContextTests()
{
    var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>().UseSqlServer("different connection string").Options;
    
    _DatabaseContext = new YourDatabaseContext(dbOptions, userServiceName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not how Alba works.